# password salt is not working after I hosted the website

Tags: php, mysql, oop, salt

I have created a small website that can download movies and tv series. There I added a user registration and login system. I used xampp latest version (php version 5.6.19) to check the website. In the registration php file, I have added password salt technique. It worked perfectly in the xampp. After I hosted my website it didn't worked. password salt is not generated and stored in the database. But username, email and password are going to the database successfully.

register.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()){

        $user = new User();
        $salt = Hash::salt(32);

        try{

            $user->create(array(
                'uname' => Input::get('uname'),
                'mail' => Input::get('mail'),
                'pass' => Hash::make(Input::get('pass'), $salt),
                'salt' => $salt

            ));

            Session::flash('home', 'You have registered successfully now you can log in !');
            Redirect::to('index.html');

        }catch(Exception $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }


}

?>
```

hash.php

```
<?php
class Hash{
public static function make($string, $salt = ''){
    return hash('sha256', $string . $salt);
}

public static function salt($length){
    return mcrypt_create_iv($length);

}

public static function unique(){
    return self::make(uniqid());

}
}
```

user.php

```
<?php
class User{
private $_db,
        $_data,
        $_sessionName,
        $_cookieName,
        $_isLoggedIn;

public function __construct($user = null){
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

    if(!$user){
        if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)){
            $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

            if($this->find($user)){
                $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
            }else{
                //process logout
            }
        }
    }else{
        $this->find($user);
    }
}


public function create($fields = array()){
    if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)){
        throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account !');
    }
}

public function find($user = null){
    if($user){
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'uname';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
        if($data->count()){
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false ){

    if(!$username && !$password && $this->exists()){
        Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
    }else{
    $user = $this->find($username);

    if($user){
            if($this->data()->pass === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)){
                    Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
                    if($remember){
                        $hash = Hash::unique();
                        $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

                        if(!$hashCheck->count()){
                            $this->_db->insert('users_session',array(
                                'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                                'hash' => $hash

                            ));
                        }else{
                            $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                        }

                        Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                    }
                    return true;    
                }
            }
        }

    return false;
}

public function exists(){
    return (!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
}

public function logout(){
    $this->_db->delete('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));
    Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
    Cookie::delete($this->_cookieName);
}

public function data(){
    return $this->_data;
}

public function isLoggedIn(){
    return $this->_isLoggedIn;
}
}
```

What may cause the problem...

Comment: difficult to say. Can we see the code from user.php?

Comment: "password salt is not generated and stored" --- those are 2 distinct symptoms.  Is it generated and not stored?

Comment: in `register.php` place user + salt instantiation inside the try/catch block, is there an error message? what data type is your password field in the database? it could be less size than value is being passed, in result it's not saved.

Comment: @dchayka data type is varchar and length of the password field is 64 and salt is 32

Comment: Please condsider switching to the dedicated functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Your functions are unsafe for hashing passwords. The mentioned function will create a safe salt on its own and include it in the hash-value, so there is no need to store it separately in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `hash` function is supported by the PHP installation on your web host.
You may try this in your `salt` function - `bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(30, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM))`

Comment: Try to `echo (mcrypt_create_iv(32));` and let me know the results.

Comment: this is the result - Mx�F���+�@�N���JT��p�$Ǖ~��I(There was a problem creating an account !

Comment: Try to use this in your `salt` function - `bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(30, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM))`

Comment: now it's working. but the problem is now login function is not working. thanks by anyways.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, then please up-vote and accept my answer.